# Contador de visitas

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugin

Necesito su ayuda para un contador de visitas, es para wordpress o php, [https://www.cerotec.net/contador.php?t=4&s=2&i=94708]

---

ACTUALIZACION

```
function under_bh_fun() {
// fichero donde se guardaran las visitas
 $fichero = "visitas.txt";

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"r");

 // sumamos una visita
 $num = fread($fptr,filesize($fichero));
 $num++;

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"w+");
 fwrite($fptr,$num);
 fclose($fptr);
 return ("<span id='days_since'>$num</span>");
}
add_shortcode('under_bh_visits', 'under_bh_fun');
```

Solo tengo un pequeño problema, y es que no da el resultado.

Comment: Si recargamos la web, se actualiza, solo.

Comment: esa dirección es tu sitio? o quieres hacer algo similar?

Comment: @jolsalazar algo similar , seria mucha ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te adjunto el código que he realizado para los alumnos de mi curso
1º Crear este código:

---

```
<?php
function contador()
{
 // fichero donde se guardaran las visitas
 $fichero = "visitas.txt";

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"r");

 // sumamos una visita
 $num = fread($fptr,filesize($fichero));
 $num++;

 $fptr = fopen($fichero,"w+");
 fwrite($fptr,$num);

 return $num;
}
?>
```

---

2º  El siguiente paso sera crear un archivo que lo llamaremos **"vistas.txt"**
Dentro de el colocaremos el numero inicial que quiere que lleve su contador, creo que el numero que deberá ir dentro de el es **"0"**

Cunado tengamos creado estos archivos lo único que debemos de hacer es poner el siguiente código en cada lugar que quieras que aparezca el contador.

---

3º Crear esta pagina

---

```
Esta pagina ha sido visitada
<?
include("contador.php");
echo contador();
?> veces
```

---

Ha funcionado siempre es puro PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias , por tu ayuda! tengo solo una pregunta, el contador se actualiza, cada vez que se recarga la web ? o como funciona esa parte?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo como hacerlo en wordpress espero te sirva.

Agregas el siguiente codigo en el function.php

//Esta es la función que se encarga de ir sumando visita a visita

```
function setVisitasPost($post_ID) {
    $key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $key , true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($post_ID, $key );
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $key , '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($post_ID, $key , $count);
    }
}

//Esta es la función que se encarga de devolver la cantidad de visitas

function getVisitasPost($post_ID){
    $key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $key , true);
    if($count==' '){
        delete_post_meta($post_ID, $key );
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $key , '0');
        return "0 Visitas";
    }
    return $count.' Visitas';
}
```

Ahora dentro del bucle(loop) insertas el siguiente código que se va a encargar de que cada vez que alguien acceda cuente las visitas

```
setVisitasPost(get_the_ID());
```

Después donde quieres que se muestra la cantidad de visitas pones el siguiente código

```
echo getVisitasPost(get_the_ID());
```

Comment: en este caso, me gustaria usarlo para shorcode, como podria hacerlo? y funciona cada vez que se recargue la web?

Comment: si funciona cada vez que recargues la web, puede ser utilizado tanto en paginas como en las entradas, lo que si te especifico que es especialmente para Wordpress, y lo mejor que tiene es que no utilizas nada fuera de Wordpress. Así que si estas trabajando en Wordpress te recomiendo que utilices ese método.